# Multiple Child Record Creation in Flow

Tags: flow

Is it possible to create a variable amount of similar records within a flow?

For instance, let's say we have a volunteer visit object that tracks all of the general information about the visit itself (Time, number of people, hours worked, etc) and then a detail object that has all of the individual registrations for all the people coming as a part of that visit. Is it possible to create a flow that would allow someone to create a variable amount registrations? The flow works great for creating the visit itself as there are a lot of different moving parts (looking up a record, editing it, creating new visits of different types, etc.) but

I'm wondering if it's possible to extend this functionality to allow the volunteer leader to register everyone in her/his group. This would involve creating new contacts if they don't exist and relating the registration to existing contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you could achieve this using a Screen, an SObject Variable, a couple of Assignments, an SObject Collection Variable and then a Descision to create a psuedo-loop. The main issue I can see with this approach is that the user interface will be a bit clunky.

If you give the user a Screen which is used to to fill in the Contact details, then add a checkbox to the bottom of the screen that says 'Add Another?' (or something similar, you could even make this step a second screen).

When that screen is submitted assign the values to the the SObject variable and add it to the SObject collection, and if they've chosen 'Add Another?' go back to the original Screen and start the process again. Otherwise carry on with your Flow and use a Fast Create to insert the SObject collection.

The whole process would look something like this:

[image: Explorer] [image: Flow]

---

Another alternative that I've not tried, but should work is to use your 'Number of People' value from the visit along with a Variable (initially set to 0), an assignment (which adds 1 to your variable). With all of these elements you can construct a loop to show the Screen the right number of times.

It would look something like this:

[image: Explorer] [image: Flow]

---

I can't think of a better way to do it with Flow as it is now, as there is no way of adding a multi-line entry on a Screen.

Nor can you loop an arbitrary amount of times easily (without doing what I've described above).

It might be worth looking into creating a Visualforce page instead if you want the user experience to be better than what Flow can offer.

Comment: This is perfect. Our current system is about this clunky (and requires a lot of syncing between our website and Salesforce which causes problems) so I'm fixing that problem and we can always use Flow for the visit creation part and then send them to a visualforce page for the registration. Thank you!